# Swift 4 Codable - Inverse Relationship

Tags: ios, object, relationship, swift4, codable

Does anyone know the best way to define an inverse relationship using the new Swift 4 codable protocol? For example, if A has an array of B. Can I also make B link to A.

Comment: I tried this once and I believe it just kept on going back and forth between encoding the parent and child until it crashed. Any updates on this?